# Is the Ability to Maintain Subscription Benefits After Switching Google Play Accounts an Exploit or Intentional Feature?

Tags: google-play, in-app-purchase, subscription

I've encountered a scenario in our Android game related to Google Play subscriptions, and I'm seeking advice on how to handle it effectively. Here's the situation:

1. User subscribes to our game using the primary account (let's call it Red).
2. The user then switches to a different account (let's call it Blue) on the Google Play Games app and uninstalls/reinstalls the game using the Blue account.
3. Despite the switch to the Blue account, the subscription purchased with the Red account remains active, allowing the user to play and progress with the Blue account.

This seems like a potential exploit, and I'm wondering if others have faced similar challenges and how they've addressed them. I'm specifically looking for insights on best practices, potential solutions, or any existing documentation that might shed light on this issue.

Thank you